# select() on socket (trouble)

Tags: c, sockets, flooding, select-function

Recently I have done [this](http://dumpz.org/14945/) part of code.

It does work, but select() works bad.
When it has got last reply from server, it begins repeating last reply string with some strange characters in the beginning of reply string.
So look at this:

```
:nacbot!monitor@nac.bot PRIVMSG testuser1 :VERSION
�C���C��monitor@nac.bot PRIVMSG testuser1 :VERSION
�C���C��monitor@nac.bot PRIVMSG testuser1 :VERSION
�C���C��monitor@nac.bot PRIVMSG testuser1 :VERSION
�C���C��monitor@nac.bot PRIVMSG testuser1 :VERSION
```

The first string is the last reply from server. So next strings are just some junk.
I tried to look for information in some search engines, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `select` that has the problem, it's the logic in your code (unsurprisingly).

If `select` returns because stdin is readable, then you still look at `c[0]` (from the last server read) - and even though you didn't read from the server this time, it's still `\n`, because you never reset it.

Move this bit of code:

```
    if (c[0] == '\n' || c[0] == '\0') {                                        
        buf[--buflen] = '\0';                                                  
        handleMessage(buf, buflen);  /* Just print message */
        buf_do_clean = 1;                                                      
    }
```

inside the `else if (rc == 1) {` block.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Now I get the whole trouble.